# Built a scroll controller, need to reverse it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

My code allows scrolling vertically in the bottom section to control scrolling horizontally in the top section.

My [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rourkemclaren/avp99eek/2/)

You'll see the colors shift through a gradient. Works pretty well. Problem is that I can't quite seem to get the inverse to work. Scrolling horizontally in the top controls scrolling in the bottom.

Any ideas?

Here's the script that makes it work:

```
// Add event listener for scrolling
$("#bottom").on("scroll", function bottomScroll() {
    var scrolledleft = parseInt($("#bottom").scrollTop()) * 1;
    console.log(scrolledleft + scrolledright)
    $("#top").scrollLeft(scrolledleft + scrolledright)
})

//Move right column to bottom initially
$("#top").scrollLeft($("#top").height())

//Get actual distance scrolled
var scrolledright = parseInt($("#top").scrollLeft())
```

Comment: You'll need a scroll event handler on #top, for starters, similar to your handler for #bottom.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, tricky part for me is converting the methods appropriately, shifting scrollTop to scrollLeft maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handlers need to temporarily cancel each other so that they don't both fire at once.  You want to calculate your position percentage based on the current scrollLeft / (width of child div - width of container), then apply that percentage to the other element, and likewise for top/height.  Also I changed the height of #top to 50% in CSS.

```js
var handler = function (e) {
  var src = e.target;
  
  // the first element that triggers this function becomes the active one, until it's done
  if (!activeScroller) activeScroller = src.id;
  else if (activeScroller != src.id) return;
  
  var $b = $("#bottom");
  var $t = $("#top");

  var scrollH = $("#bottom-content").height() - $b.height();
  var scrollW = $("#top-content").width() - $t.width();

  var scrollPct = 0;

  if (src.id == "top") {
    if (scrollW > 0) {
      scrollPct = $t.scrollLeft() / scrollW;
    }

    $b.scrollTop(scrollH * scrollPct);
  } else {
    if (scrollH > 0) {
      scrollPct = $b.scrollTop() / scrollH;
    }

    $t.scrollLeft(scrollW * scrollPct);
  }
  
  // give all animations a chance to finish
  setTimeout(function () { activeScroller = ""; }, 100);
};
var activeScroller = "";
$("#top,#bottom").on("scroll", handler);
```

```css
#top {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  background: red;
}

#top-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 2000px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, blue);
}

#bottom {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  background: green;
  z-index: 100;
}

#bottom-content {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, orange, green);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top">
  <div id="top-content"></div>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
    <div id="bottom-content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:
https://jsfiddle.net/1p7gp72h/1/

I'm not sure what your end goal is here.

```
$("#top").on("scroll", function topScroll() {
    var scrolledleft = parseInt($("#top").scrollTop()) * 1;

    $("#bottom").scrollLeft(scrolledleft + scrolledright)
});

#top {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 5000px;
  height: 100%;

  overflow: auto;
  background: red;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: If you scroll down in the bottom half of my fiddle you'll see the top section also scroll, from left to right. I'm trying to make the same function work for scrolling in the top half and making the bottom half scroll too.

Comment: Do you want a horizontal scroll bar to appear in the middle of the screen? Normally they only appear at the bottom of the browser window. You want the horizontal scroll to link to scroll vertically?

Answer (score 0):

Scroll to left ::

```
$('div').scrollLeft(1000);
```

Scroll back to normal/ scroll to right ::

```
$('div.slick-viewport').scrollLeft(-1000);
```